# D3 get path subsections

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to draw a long path and then isolate subsections of it to make some modifications. The closest logic I can see is this - http://bl.ocks.org/explunit/6082362. This example involves repeatedly drawing subsections of the line. To make it faster, I would like to draw the long path in advance and cut sections out of it. I've found the functions `getpointatlength`, `getTotalLength`, etc. to achieve point wise subsections but they don't let me access the exact interpolated path between these points. Any idea how?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: You can use the same code as the link I have provided. Pick a stretch you like, let's say the one which has speed = 3000, and if you can tell me how to get the path itself for that stretch then the question is answered.

Comment: sry not able to understand the problem are you saying that in teh example above the path is defined by d attribute M89.99999999999999,78.57142857142857Q81.99999999999999,133.42857142857142,89.99999999999999,147.14285714285714C101.99999999999999,167.71428571428572,145.99999999999997,200.28571428571428,169.99999999999997,215.71428571428572S220,244.85714285714286,...  so you want to break this in to subsection of circle points in the graph.

Comment: @Cyril - The total path is defined by the d attribute. I want to get a partial continuous chunk of this path. For convenience sake, we can assume the chunk is identified by the circle at each end of it in the link mentioned in the question.

Comment: So for instance one of the the chunks to be isolated is the one connecting (449.99999999999994,284.2857142857143) and (490,421.42857142857144)

Comment: OK but you could have used some Regex to break this up right?

Comment: Is it as simple as grepping for a particular start and end point and removing everything that occurs on the other side of it? The letters specifying how to connect the points are covered accurately?

Comment: @Codoremifa yea you can simply grep its there are many SO answeres dealing with this..beside that, one thing more, I would like to emphasize(in the fiddle you shared in teh post)  check the circle cx/cy you will see the same cx/cy coordinates in the d attribute of that path. that way you can do a subsection via those points...

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. However, grepping by points will fail if the line has intersections. do you have any hints for that? I think I didn't get any of the SO answers because I probably am not using the exact words I need to use to search. If you could point me to one I'd appreciate it.